How to Run Live Unit Test Against Azure Function Project?
When I attempt to run a Live Unit Test of code from an Azure Function App, it will build once, and then fails to be build the nest time a change is made, even though building it manually and running the test from the Test Explored works just fine.
I created a brand new Solution, and Brand new Function App, and Brand new MS Test project, and added this class to the Function App Project:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Poc
    {
        public bool IsTrue { get; } = true;
    }
}

  

And this test
using FunctionApp1;

namespace FuncitonApp.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var sut = new Poc();
            Assert.IsTrue(sut.IsTrue);
        }
    }
}
  

I’m able to manually build the solution no issues. Able to run the MS test in the normal Test Explorer, no issues, but when I attempt to run the test as a Live Unit Test, I get the following Live Unit Test Output:
[3:33:09 PM Info] Live Unit Testing started.
[3:33:09 PM Info] Building solution.
[3:33:10 PM Info] Loading projects.
[3:33:12 PM Info] Triggering NuGet package restore.
[3:33:14 PM Info] Building project 'FunctionApp1'.
[3:33:28 PM Info] Build failed for project 'FunctionApp1'.
[3:33:28 PM Error] Build completed with failures. Errors were logged under file:///C:/Users/DarylLaBar/source/lut/FunctionApp1/v2/0/diag/build.minimal.log
[3:37:31 PM Info] Building 1 test projects.
[3:37:32 PM Info] Loading projects.
[3:37:32 PM Info] Building project 'FunctionApp1'.
[3:37:41 PM Info] Build failed for project 'FunctionApp1'.
[3:37:41 PM Error] Build completed with failures. Errors were logged under file:///C:/Users/DarylLaBar/source/lut/FunctionApp1/v2/0/diag/build.minimal.log

  

With this as the build.minimal.log:
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 1 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 2 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 3 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 4 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 5 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 6 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 7 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 8 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 9 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): error : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): error : Unable to build Azure Functions metadata for obj\Debug\net8.0\FunctionApp1.dll

Build FAILED.

C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 1 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 2 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 3 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 4 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 5 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 6 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 7 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 8 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): warning : Could not write function metadata. Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Beginning retry 9 of 10 in 1000ms.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): error : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\Users\DarylLaBar\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.17.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(110,5): error : Unable to build Azure Functions metadata for obj\Debug\net8.0\FunctionApp1.dll
    9 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:09.37
  


Install Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces package with Version 8.0.0 in your project.

I have implemented your requirement in my environment by creating a Function App and test project using .NET 8.0. I could build and run the tests as Live Unit Testing as well as in test explorer.

Created a Http trigger Azure function.
Added a Poc class to the Function project.
Created a MS Test project and added the function project as reference.
Navigate to Test=>Clear all test results:



Navigate to Test=>Live Unit Testing=>Reset Live Unit testing for solution:



Configure the Live Unit Testing again:




I could successfully test the project in Live unit Testing:


[6:14:19 PM Info] Live Unit Testing stopped.  
[6:14:34 PM Info] Clearing test selection.  
[6:14:34 PM Info] Clearing persisted test results.  
[6:14:34 PM Info] Deleting workspace folder 'C:\Users\uname\Downloads\FunctionApp11\FunctionApp11\UnitTestProject1\FunctionApp11'.  
[6:17:18 PM Info] Live Unit Testing stopped.  
[6:20:54 PM Info] Live Unit Testing started.  
[6:20:54 PM Info] Building solution.  
[6:20:54 PM Info] Loading projects.  
[6:20:54 PM Info] Triggering NuGet package restore.  
[6:21:01 PM Info] Build completed successfully.


I've followed all your steps and the results are unchanged.

What is the version of the package Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces you are using?

8.0.0.0.  thanks for looking into it.

Can you try upgrading it to the latest version?

8.0.0 is the latest version.

Can you try by creating a new project?

Didn't change anything.

What is the version of your Visual Studio?

Visual Studio Enterprise 64 bit 17.9.7

Same with Visual studio Enterprise 64 bit version 17.10.1

and 17.10.5 ... :(
